Is it a crime to use a scam driving licence as ID online?
There is a question on Travel.SE about an apparent "international driving permit" that is confirmed in an answer to be a very well known scam.  However it does appear to provide a card that looks like a driving licence to the untrained eye for (when a UK client is detected) €35.
Obviously to use such a card in the commission of a crime could be crime in itself.  Suppose one submitted an image of such a card to a prompt of "Provide Photo ID" with ones own data on it would this be a crime?
I am particularly thinking about online services, social media like Parler who lost all the data and adult content age checks.

I would expect that it is very context specific. Often "provide photo ID" would be defined somewhere to be limited to government issued photo ID, so, at a minimum it would be a breach of contract. Sometimes it would be a crime, sometimes not.

The answer is very context and jurisdiction specific.
Often "provide photo ID" would be defined somewhere to be limited to government issued photo ID, so, at a minimum it would be a breach of contract.
Sometimes it would be a crime, sometimes not.
For example, if you used a fake ID to gain access to something that it is a crime to access if you are underage, it would probably be a crime. Similarly, using a fake ID to get the benefits of residency you don't have, or to avoid a traffic ticket, or to misrepresent your age when age is relevant, would often be crimes. Using a fake name with an intent to harm the other party or benefit yourself would often be a crime in contexts more weighty than social media or a blog.
Sometimes it would constitute criminal fraud, the definition of which varies quite a bit from state to state and country to country, and is often broken up into many sub-crimes that are each more specific.
Sometimes holding an ID out to be from a government agency when it is not (e.g. a military ID, or a law enforcement badge, or a purported driver's license) is a crime in and of itself.
